# How to get Firebase hosting to return 503 status code for the server maintenance page?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Does anyone know a good way to put a static Firebase site into maintenance mode while performing some database upgrade?

I've tried to configure the rewrite with custom headers but it's not working. Firebase hosting appears to return both the default status (200) and the custom status (503) in the response.

My `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "status",
            "value": "503"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Response headers from chrome:
[image: Chrome Inspect]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope. We end up building the server maintenance page into the single-page app.